# Get name from hashtag using regex

Tags: php, regex, hashtag

I have this string/content:

`@Salome`, `@Jessi H` and `@O'Ren` were playing at the `@Lean`'s yard with "`@Ziggy`" the mouse.

Well, I am trying to get all names focuses above. I have used `@` symbol to create like a hash to be used in my web. If you note, there are names with spaces between like `@Jessi H` and characters before and after like `@Ziggy`. So, I don't my if you suggest me another way to manage the hash in another way to get it works correctly. I was thinking that for user that have white spaces, could write the hash with quotes like `@"Jessi H"`. What do you think? Other examples:

```
@Lean's => @"Lean"'s  
@Jessi H => @"Jessi H"  
"@Jessi H" => (sorry, I don't know how to parse it)  
@O'Ren => @"O'Ren"
```

What I have do?
I'm starting using regex in php, but some SO questions have been usefull for me to get started, so, these are my tries using **preg_match_all** function firstly:

Result of `/@(.*?)[,\" ]/`:

```
Array ( [0] => Salome [1] => Jessi [2] => Charlie [3] => Lean's [4] => Ziggy" ) )
```

Result of `/@"(.*?)"/` for names like `@"name"`:

```
Empty array
```

Guys, I don't expect that you do it all for me. I think that a pseudo-code or something like this will be helpful to guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Are you printing this data, or is it user entered?

Comment: Hi, I just print it via `print_r($hashes)` from `preg_match_all($regex, $content, $hashes);`

Comment: But what is the source of the string you are searching?

Comment: @circusdei, my writing is terrible, sorry, it is not my native lang... Well. I have update the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following regex: `'/@(?:"([^"]+)|([^\b]+?))\b/'`

This will return two match groups, the first containing any quoted names (eg `@"Jessi H"` and `@"O'Ren"`), and the second containing any unquoted names (eg `@Salome`, `@Leon`)

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/@(?:"([^"]+)|([^\b]+?))\b/', '@Salome, @"Jessi H" and @"O\'Ren" were playing at the @Lean\'s yard with "@Ziggy" the mouse.', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @Salome
            [1] => @"Jessi H
            [2] => @"O'Ren
            [3] => @Lean
            [4] => @Ziggy
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => Jessi H
            [2] => O'Ren
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Salome
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => Lean
            [4] => Ziggy
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I didn't knew how powerfull regex is. However, I have used your regex and `@"Jessi H"` stills get only `Jessi`, and for `@"O'Ren"` I get only `O`

Comment: I fixed a bug I'd introduced a few minutes ago and updated the answer, can you try it again?

Comment: I have copied/pasted your code and it did not work. However, you have done a lot for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Heyy, after three hours I get the error: it's not yours! it's mine. Fo some reason there was a script runnning in the backgorund that scaped my symbols. Hey! Thank you so much, your regex runs perfect. :)

Comment: Ouch! It happens to the best of us. Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting these requirements or can you choose them? If you can set the requirements, I would suggest using `_` instead of spaces, which would allow you to use the regex:

`/@(.+) /`

If spaces must be allowed and you're going with quotes, then the quotes should probably span the entire name, allowing for this regex:

`/@\"(.+)\" /`

Comment: Hi. Well, the users in the web likes to use name with spaces, so I try to do my best to keep the spaces. If not... we will see